# How to create the date wise backup file using T-SQL script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote the following script but it shows an error due to the `+` sign in `@command` argument. Could anyone suggest how I can get rid of this error?

```
USE msdb;
GO

--add a job
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'FullBackup';
GO

USE msdb;
GO

--add jobsteps to jobsteps
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(90);
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @commandtxt VARCHAR(100);

SET @fileName = 'D:\SQL server\BackUp\'; 
--SET @db_name = 'AdventureWorks_';    
SET @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),112);
SET @fileName = @fileName + @db_name + RTRIM(@fileDate) + '.bak';

SET @commandtxt = N'''BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO DISK =N''' + @fileName + ''' WITH INIT';

EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'FullBackup',
    @step_name = N'Weekly Full Backup',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = 'BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO DISK =N''' + @fileName + ''' WITH INIT',
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5;
GO

--Create a Schedule for this job, backup, occurs once a week each friday at 11:59
EXEC sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'WeeklyBackup1',
    @freq_type = 8,
    @freq_interval = 32,
    @freq_recurrence_factor = 1,
    @active_start_time = 235900;
GO

--attach the schedule to the job
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
    @job_name = N'FullBackup',
    @schedule_name = N'WeeklyBackup1';
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'FullBackup';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @commandtxt = N'BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO DISK =N''' + @fileName + ''' WITH INIT'


EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'FullBackup',
    @step_name = N'Weekly Full Backup',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = @Commandtxt,
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5;
GO
.
.
.
```